# How reliable is AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I execute some code using android `AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result>`

If there are no **exceptions** during the execution of:

```
@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(Object[] params) {
// some methods here
}
```

Are there any **possibilites** that following code **might not execute**:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Boolean o) {
//System.out.println("Hello");  
}
```

In my application i put a **boolean** value(**true**) in *SharedPreferences* and i need to change it to **false** after the **execution is finished**.
I use this values to detect if this task is already running.*For some reason i can't use* `.isCancled() /*and|or */ .getStatus()`as i do not store any **reference** to this task.

Answer (score 2):

> Are there any possibilites that following code might not execute:

`onPostExecute()` will not be called if you `cancel()` the `AsyncTask`. You should `cancel()` the `AsyncTask` when it is no longer needed and may crash, such as when the activity that executed the `AsyncTask` is destroyed.

Also, `onPostExecute()` will not be called if your process is terminated, for any reason.

> In my application i put a boolean value(true) in SharedPreferences and i need to change it to false after the execution is finished. I use this values to detect if this task is already running.

That is not a very good choice. For example, if your process is terminated while your task is running, your `SharedPreferences` will report that the task is running the next time your app starts up. Do not use a persistent data store for non-persistent information.

> For some reason i can't use .isCancled() /*and|or */ .getStatus()as i do not store any reference to this task.

Then store a reference to the task, such as from a retained fragment.

Comment: Will AsyncTask get **canceled/stoped** if the Activity that created it is destroyed?

Comment: @Harsh: Only if you `cancel()` it. Again, *you* should `cancel()` it when the activity is being destroyed, as you cannot safely attempt to update the UI of a destroyed activity. And, if you are not updating the UI from `onPostExecute()`, then perhaps you do not need an `AsyncTask` in the first place, but instead could use just an ordinary `Thread`.

Comment: Is creating a static reference a good practice for background tasks?
I run this asyncTask form *services running in background*. Wouldn't **Task-Killers** (*if any*) will remove the reference creating a (`NullPointerException`). So, i am running a (**new**) asyncTask every time i need.

Comment: @Harsh: "Is creating a static reference a good practice for background tasks?" -- not generally. "I run this asyncTask form services running in background." -- then you do not need `AsyncTask`. Use a `Thread`.

Comment: Can you point me in right direction. I am having trouble understanding Thread.
I viewed [this](https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/index.html) and some other examples.
Most results on the internet for running background code are for **AsyncTask**.

Comment: @Harsh: You only need `AsyncTask` when you have something that needs to be done on the main application thread when the background work is done. There is very little that we *ever* want a service doing on the main application thread, and so services should not be using `AsyncTask`, as it is wasteful (and actually harmful to the user, due to the way Linux process priorities work). "I am having trouble understanding Thread" -- it is part of standard Java and has been around for 20 years. If you have questions about how to use `Thread`, please ask a separate Stack Overflow question.

Comment: I shall be more precise. I have a download task that is triggered in the background when ever user shakes the phone. I if user shakes the phone while still downloading i don't want to perform any action.Should i use Thread or continue with the AsyncTask.

Comment: @Harsh: You should use a `Thread`. You have no need to do anything on the main application thread.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time